# Python Multiprocessing makes system unresponsive

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am processing several datasets (which are encapsulated with custom python object and are serialized on disk) with a bunch of operations that take about 10/15 seconds for each. I have enclosed these operations on a Process and i am calling 160 processes, for scheduling.

I set `Semaphore(6)` since I have an 8 core CPU.

The problem is that around process 80, the RAM gets full, the Swap is also full, and the system gets completely unresponsive.

I have also made effort to use garbage collector, but it made no difference.

It starts running normally, and when time passes, the system completely freezes. Here is a screenshot of `htop` right before crash:
[Swap is at 5GB but it gets at 8GB before crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y3AZ.png)

My system is:
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- i7 2600 4 Cores (8 Threads)
- GTX 1060 3GB
- Ram DDR3 8GB

Here is the code:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import time
from pathlib import Path

import gc


def main():
    all_args_list = load_datasets()

    processes = []
    queue_res = mp.Queue()
    cpu_lim = mp.Semaphore(mp.cpu_count() - 2) # Use 6 of my 8 cores

    for i, some_args in enumerate(all_args_list):

        p = mp.Process(target=process_routine, args=(some_args, queue_res, cpu_lim))
        processes.append(p)

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    results = [queue_res.get() for p in processes]

    save(results)


def process_routine(some_args, queue_obj, cpu_lim):
    cpu_lim.acquire()

    # Do my operations ....
    process_result_dict = my_operations(some_args)

    # Save process result
    res_obj.put(process_result_dict)

    gc.collect()
    cpu_lim.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How should i proceed in order to prevent python from hijacking all memory?
Why does RAM usage increase overtime? Shouldnt garbage collector collect old objects?

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

I changed the multiple processes to a Pool. The problem is that now it is only running each process individually, using `apply_async()` or `apply()`:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply_async(process_routine, args=(my_args,)) for id, my_args in enumerate(datasets)]
```

Comment: Yes, consuming all of your systems resources will generally make your computer less responsive. Is the question how to reduce the resource usage? 180 procs is a ton if they are all doing work concurrently.

Comment: In most cases you want your pool size to be equal to the number of CPUs.

Comment: @jordanm, yes, the question is why the swap and ram get exhausted (shouldnt gc clean the old objects) and how to prevent it from total system crash

Comment: If you're using a `Pool`, get rid of the `Semaphore`, and just explicitly size the pool to `mp.cpu_count() - 2`. `apply` is expected to run individually; `apply_async` isn't, but we don't know how much real work you're doing per task; if it's small, and the arguments are expensive to serialize, that'll eliminate all your savings.

Comment: As for gc not working: GC when forking is worse than not GC-ing; it touches most of the reference counts, causing most of copy-on-write memory to be copied immediately. I'd suggest [changing your start method to `'forkserver'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), removing the `gc.collect`, and if that's not enough, setting a `maxtasksperchild=SOMENUMBER` so child processes are collected intermittently and restarted from scratch (which is the only way to be sure you release all the memory).

Comment: Looking at the way you’re using the Pool in your edit, and based on the main program, I think you should be able to just use one of the various `map` methods. It will simplify things drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than start 160 processes, you should try using a pool with a size equal to the number of CPUs on your system as a starting point. Take a look at [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor). No need to do your own semaphore logic when this can manage the process pool/resources for you.

Comment: I already changed it to a pool `multiprocessing.Pool` but now it does not seem to run the Processes parallel

Comment: Can you post your completely updated code? Did you update `process_routine` as well? Unless you have a specific reason to use `multiprocessing` please give `ProcessPoolExecutor` a try following the examples in the docs.

Comment: @ajomc What gives you that impression? Can you share the modified version of your program?